# No for loop will run inside for loop. Testing for primes

Tags: java, math, for-loop, nested-loops

For some reason, my second for loop will NOT run at all. In fact, any other type of for loop I put in there wont run either. I tested just putting a simple for loop right after the println("looping until we divide by...); and that wouldnt run either. The simple for loop I added for testing was this.

```
for (int k = 0; k > 10; k++) {
   System.out.println(k);
}
```

Which would obviously just print the values from 0 to 10. But it wont execute. Here is the actual code for the program. In case anyone is wondering what it is supposed to do, it takes a range, hardcoded for testing to be from 100 to 1000. It checks to see if the last number, 1000, is a prime by looping through all numbers from 2 to 1000/2 to see if the remainder is 0, if it is, the number is not a prime, break the loop and check the next number. If the number makes it through without setting isPrime to false, then it is a prime, and because we start with the largest number, it is the largest prime number in the list and therefor we break the outer loop and print it. Yes this is part of a homework assignment using RMI. I have the RMI working completely fine but the algorithm was giving me trouble so I decided to start with a fresh program and get the algorithm right before I put it into my PrimeImpl class. Here is the code.

```
public class PrimeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int first = 100;
        int last = 1000;
        int biggest = 0;
        boolean isPrime = true;
        int i;

        for (i = last; i > first - 1; i--) {

            isPrime = true;
            System.out.println("Assume " + i + " is prime.");
            int halfI = i / 2;
            System.out.println("Looping until we divide by " + halfI);

            for (int j = 2; j > halfI; j++) {

                // Loop not entering. This statement doesnt print. Why?
                System.out.println(i + " modulus " + j + " = " + i % j);
                if (i % j == 0) {

                    isPrime = false;
                    System.out.println("Not a prime");
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isPrime == true) {
                System.out.println(i + " is a prime");
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isPrime == true) {
            biggest = i;
        }

        if (isPrime == false) {
            biggest = 0;
        }

        System.out.println(biggest);
    }
}
```

I know there are other ways to test numbers for prime, but for the time being I would like to try and use my method here. It seems that it would be efficient IF it works because as soon as I get the first prime number, its done.

Comment: Could you also add the consul output. That way we know what print statements are reached.

Comment: run:
Assume 1000 is prime.
Looping until we divide by 500
89u3489ty9ht8whtiwth
1000 is a prime
1000
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Sorry about the garble text there, I had that in there just to see if that would even execute and it did, but then I removed that code from my code before i posted it...just in case you're wondering where that string of text that starts after 500 but before 1000.

Comment: Nice question. Enjoy playing with primes. Smart people have spent their entire careers doing just that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int k = 0; k > 10; k++) {
   System.out.println(k);
}
```

`k` is not greater than 10, so loop will will never execute. I think what want is `k<10`, isn't it?

```
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
   System.out.println(k);
}
```

Comment: Maybe i'm getting confused with how a for loop works but isnt the terminating statement mean it will run until that statement is true? So for example, it should keep looping UNTIL k > 10, and with k starting at 0 and doing k++, eventually k will become 11 at which point k > 10 equals true and the loop ends.

Comment: no you're right and i'm a complete idiot. I just realized the error in my code. My second for loop terminating statement should be j < halfI not j > halfI. Even though my first for loop, i had the logic right in my head, for whatever reason for my second for loop I had it backwards as I explain in my comment above. I will flag this answer as the correct answer as soon as it lets me. Apparently I have to wait 5 minutes.

Comment: @RichardChase: Sorry I went out. I hope you are clear now. Good luck!